# res.send() changed my object sub-object content

Tags: express, object

This is very strange. In my express server, I send an object back to the frontend. The object is console logged as below:
[image: object contents with key "Logssets" is the sub-object, whose name changed after recieved in the frontend]

I try to JSON.stringy(wellObj) before send or just purely res.send(wellObj). The frontend always got the same wrong content as shown as below:
[image: "Logssets" first element (sub-object) have the wrong "name". Their 'id's are correct]

Comment: By that... I'm guessing you mean attributes like `curvesInfo`, `wellinfo`, etc...

Comment: Try using `res.json(wellObj)` ...

Comment: no. the "name" has been changed. The "id" is keeping the correct value. Other attributes is ok(I have not check them yet as they are more complex)

Comment: Are u referring the ellipsis **(...)** ...??

Comment: no. just the "name" attr of the first element of "Logssets", which is "fullcorelas", but got "fullcorelith"(which is the "name " of the second element)

Comment: And you are certain that nothing is manipulating the data on the server before sending to the client (after logging)... or on the client after it has received the message (before logging)...??

Comment: very sure. I found the displaying wrong "name" then try to debug and found this strange problem. Then trying to check the object just before sending in server side and just after receiving in the browser side.

Comment: Could u add screenshots of the server code fetching and sending.... and also the client code request...??

Answer (score 0):

I am still not very clear about what happened, while I have solved the problem, kind of solved it:-(. In my previous testing, I used the same dataset to represent two datasets/records in the database but only give the different names and ids(all the data is the same). The res.send() seems smart enough and trying do something during sending, which make the sent obj's subObj element changed a little(the name changed from "fullcorelas" to "fullcorelith").
I have not change any of my code, but only really using the different datasets at the beginning when creating the database. Then the res.send() did the job properly(won't confuse the 'fullcorelas' with 'fullcorelith') as expected.
It is really strange while if I use the same dataset to create two records in the database, then later when I try to fetch the two records from the database, the res.send() will trying to change my obj's element name to the same for these two records. 
I may come back to study what's really happening of res.send() later if I am not so busy to catch up the project deadline. But I guess it may be related to the depth of the obj structure.